# How to send post url request and get response return file download into local directory in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know how can I send a post request url and get response  return file download into local directory in C# .net? I have the following code which manage to send a post url request and response  with the zip file. how can I save the file into the directory?

```
    var client = new WebClient();

    var values = new NameValueCollection();
    values["StartDate"] = "18-Sep-2016 00:00";
    values["EndDate"] = "23-Sep-2016 00:00";
    values["CampaignName"] = "null";
    values["SearchBy"] = "Evaluation";
    values["CustomFilter"] = "rep.CALLDNIS like '#0400000000%'";


    var response = client.UploadValues("http://test.com", values);

    client.DownloadFile(response, @"C:\myfile.zip");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801681/downloading-a-file-via-an-http-post-where-am-i-going-wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UploadValues` returns a type of `byte[]`.

You can use
 `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, response)` to save it as a file.

OR

Check here [How to zip (and unzip) byte[] in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163094/how-to-zip-and-unzip-byte-in-c) on how to save it as a zip file.